# How to plot two graphs with same Y-axis scale but different values

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I have been trying to create a plot that shows the difference between two years of the same value. For comparison purposes I want the Y-axis to have the same breaks, however the data differs a lot between years. GGplot automatically adjusts the axis to this, is there any way to prevent this?

Current issue is visible in the picture. I would like both axis to range up to three hundred as I will eventually compare it to 2022 where the data also ranges higher than 2021.

```
# Plot for 2020
defplot20 <- ggplot(def20, aes(x=date, y=neerslagtekort)) +
  geom_line()  +  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week", date_minor_breaks = "1 week",
               date_labels = "%d-%b", expand = c(0, 0)) +
  labs(y="Y", x="X") + ggtitle("2020") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 350, by = 25))

# Plot for 2021 
defplot21 <- ggplot(def21, aes(x=date, y=neerslagtekort)) +
  geom_line()  +  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week", date_minor_breaks = "1 week",
               date_labels = "%d-%b", expand = c(0, 0)) +
  labs(y="Y", x="X") + ggtitle("2021") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 350, by = 25))

ggarrange(defplot20, defplot21)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: What about merging them in the same graph, each line a different color? Would that be an option?

Comment: That might actually be better than making a figure with three loose plots. Thanks! I will try this first, in the case my supervisors would want to see a different graph I will paste a dput for @Quinten. In any case, thanks to both of you for the quick responses!

Answer (score 0):

As @wernor commented, merging the graphs in one graph seems a good option if you want to compare these graphs.

If you want to put them next to each other using `ggarange` your code is pretty close you just need to add the `limits` argument to your `scale_y_continuous` to force the axis scale to be the same:

```
# Plot for 2020
defplot20 <- ggplot(def20, aes(x=date, y=neerslagtekort)) +
  geom_line()  +  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week", date_minor_breaks = "1 week",
               date_labels = "%d-%b", expand = c(0, 0)) +
  labs(y="Y", x="X") + ggtitle("2020") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 350), breaks = seq(0, 350, by = 25))

# Plot for 2021 
defplot21 <- ggplot(def21, aes(x=date, y=neerslagtekort)) +
  geom_line()  +  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week", date_minor_breaks = "1 week",
               date_labels = "%d-%b", expand = c(0, 0)) +
  labs(y="Y", x="X") + ggtitle("2021") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 350), breaks = seq(0, 350, by = 25))

ggarrange(defplot20, defplot21)
```

Be aware! When using `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(), breaks = seq())` you always need to know your data. Otherwise you could make mistakes with zooming to far in or out, losing sight of data and/or datapoints.

And without the dput it was not possible to check this code beforehand on your data.

Comment: Ah perfect, I know the data so limits() would have been a great option. This is a nice alternative for if we end up having thee plots next to each other. This function does exactly what I want, but expected from breaks. Thank you very much!

Comment: yeah they seem kind of similar (I had the same problem with these arguments), limits determines the total lenght of your axis, while breaks allows you to specify the distance between the axis ticks.

Comment: That explains I didn't immediately think of using the limits() argument. Thanks for clearing it up, that will save me a lot of trouble in the future when running into similar situations.